# How to solve a system of DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{eqnarray} x' + z &=& e^t \\
-x + x' + y' + z' &=& 0\\
x + 2y + z' &=& e^t
\end{eqnarray}$$

Solve by systematic elimination.

I tried to use differential operator notation and then eliminate until only one variable is left but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Maybe you could add what you have tried, or where you have gotten stuck?

Comment: I've added what I have tried. Can you help?

Comment: Sorry I can't, someone will come along shortly I'm sure.  Welcome to math.se however!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the derivative of the last equation. Doing so we get that $x'+2y'+z'' = e^t$. From the second equation, we know that $y' = x-x'-z'$. If we substitute this into the previous expression we get that

$$x'+2(x-x'-z')+z'' = 2x-x'-2z'+z'' = e^t.$$

From the first equation we know that $z = e^t - x'$ and so $z' = e^t - x''$ and $z'' = e^t - x'''$. Substituting, we have that:

$$2x-x'-2(e^t-x'')+(e^t-x''') = e^t.$$

After simplification we have that

$$2x-x'+2x''-x''' = 2e^t.$$

Can you solve this? Do you see how you can use this technique for the others?

Comment: oh yes sir, you're so smart!!